# WEBRTC got remote scream but only video doesn't display in view(making SFU)

Tags: server, webrtc

[image]

As the image shown, I got the remote stream from the server and I tried to attach the stream to video, but it is not displaying any video on the view.

It totally works in the local. Also, the turn/stun server works in the other app or server I created. Moreover, I can notice they are connected as chatting or any other functions are working between them.

I am trying to figure out why it is not displaying the video, but really stuck now on.

--host
[image: host]

--client
[image]
Is there any solution for this or any suggestion to try?

This is the picture that works in local

--host
[image]
--client
[image]
PLUS) There is no error I got in the server or in the view.

Answer (score 0):

All the problem was candidate... make sure you emit the candidate to server and get back the candidate to client...